# Is this valid reactJS code?

Tags: reactjs

New to ReactJS. Got this on a "join reactJS event questionary" but was unable to compile it. It seems to be missing a React Component class definition for the Item and List.
Is this shorthand style valid?

[image]

Comment: Adding to the answers provided below, perhaps these posts may be useful? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=stateless+functional+components

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this shorthand style valid?

yes, it is valid code, `List` and `Items` are [`Stateless functional components`](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components)

---

In order to run this code you need use [`babel`](https://babeljs.io/) with [`babel-preset-react`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are [stateless functions](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions), aka "pure components". They take their props as their only parameter and return the render results. If you do not need to keep track of any state, they are very lightweight both to understand mentally and in terms of the resources needed by React to manage them.

As to why you were unable to compile it, possibly you do not enable the right ES6/ES2015 features in whichever compiler you're using. You are using among other things `super` calls, object destructuring (in the parameters) and arrow functions. For help with this, provide the specific error message.

Answer (score 0):

It is a valid javascript es6 code, except that multiple dynamic children (here the list of Items) need to have key prop https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children